# Guarda dato en ManyToManyField con Django

Tags: html, python, django, django-templates

Buenas estoy teniendo un problema que no se como resolver, quiero guardar datos en un campo ManyToManyField desde el views.py de un form  de HTML. explico en códigos y mis intentos.

```
models.py
class Cursoos(models.Model):
    curso = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    division = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
       curso_y_division = self.curso + "-" + self.division
       return curso_y_division

class Preceptor(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   cursos = models.ManyToManyField(Cursoos) <----- este es el campo que queriero guardar los datos
```

vista

```
views.py
def agregar_preceptor(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
        nombre = request.POST['nombre']
        cursos = request.POST['cursos'] <--- se que tiene que ser un array (Creo) para recibir todos los datos pero aun intentando asi no me funciono
        usuario = User.objects.get(id = 29) <----- este es solo un usuario de ejemplo no hay importancia
        preceptor = Preceptor(user=usuario, nombre=nombre, cursos=cursos)
        preceptor.save()
   cursos = Cursoos.objects.all()
   cont ={
      "cursos":cursos
   }
   return render(request, "secretario/agregar_preceptor.html", cont)
```

html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action...>
           <input ...>
           <select name="cursos" multiple>
                {% for curso in cursos %}
                    <option value="{{curso.id}}">{{curso}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
           </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

claraciones:
es la primera ves que utilizo el  de igual modo que quiero guardar algo desde un formulario que cree yo, así que quizás este mal hecho o algo por el estilo, así aun si esta mal del todo y me pueden ayudar a orientarme hacia la respuesta se lo agradecería mucho. Soy relativamente nuevo con Django pero nunca había intentado esto, de igual modo simplifique el código para no mostrar partes que no aportan nada

Answer (score 1):

Al obtener los datos en la vista prueba de usar

```
cursos = request.POST.getlist('cursos')
```

Evita usar

```
request.POST['cursos']
```

Y usa

```
request.POST.get('cursos')
```

o

```
request.POST.getlist('cursos')
```

Eso es para mayor seguridad ya que con la función `get()` y `getlist()` puedes establecer valores por defecto en caso que no llegara nada desde el formulario, por ejemplo:

Imagina que tienes en el formulario un campo llamado *curso* y suponemos que debería de llegar `curso programación en python` pero por algun motivo el valor llega vacio (pude que el usuario haya modificado el formulario o se haya producido un error), podrias declarar

```
request.POST.get('cursos', 'curso de HTML')
```

Aquí, *curso de HTML* sería el valor que obtendrías en caso de que llegase vacio. Puedes establecer también un `None` y comprobar si la variable cursos tiene contenido o no.

De todos modos te invito a que le eches un vistazo a las [Vistas basadas en Classes](https://ccbv.co.uk/) ya que ahorran mucho tiempo y automatizan todo el proceso de los formularios